# How to solve the error when compile the hadoop2.7.3?

Tags: maven, hadoop

The software I used as following: 
[image: the version]
And I meet the error as following: 
[image]
The system I used is Centos 7 and the JDK I used is 1.7.0_07. Anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some of the libraries required to build hadoop. Do you have all this installed?

```
yum -y install wget gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake libtool zlib-devel cmake openssl openssl-devel snappy snappy-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel protobuf protobuf-devel
```

If libraries are not the case, you can find this project useful. This is a bash script which builds hadoop from scratch. May be there you'll find a step you've missed:

https://github.com/hadoopfromscratch/hadoopfromscratch